# Loop through subfolders by name

Tags: vba, outlook

The folder path is *"Mailbox - IT Support Center"\"Onshore - Josh"\"Completed"*.

I want to know the total number of emails in each person's completed mailbox from yesterday.
There are about 25 mailboxes but they all follow the same path starting at *Mailbox - IT Support Center*.

The script works except for the loop. It iterates through to the second folder but it still searches the first mailbox. Most likely something wrong with objfolder.

```vb
Sub CompletedEmailCount()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder  
    Dim MailItem  
    Dim EmailCount As Integer  
    Dim strFolderName  
    Dim FolderName() As Variant  
    Dim i As Integer  
    Dim objFolder1  

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
    strFolderName = ("Mailbox - IT Support Center")

    ReDim FolderName(3) 'change this to how many folders you have  
    'assign each folder name on the array elements  
         FolderName(1) = ("Onshore - Josh")  
         FolderName(2) = ("OnShore - Ashton")  
         FolderName(3) = ("OnShore - Beth")  

    'loop through each foldername  
    For i = 1 To 3  
    On Error Resume   
    Next  
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders(strFolderName).Folders(FolderName(i)).Folders   ("completed")  
    On Error GoTo 0  
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then GoTo skip  

    For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items  
        If DatePart("d", Date - 1) = DatePart("d", MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then EmailCount = EmailCount + 1      
    Next
skip:  
    Next  

    MsgBox "Completed Email Totals from Yesterday: " & EmailCount

End Sub
```

Comment: you say the path to the folders is The folder path is "Mailbox - IT Support Center"\"Onshore - Josh"\"Completed"......  but are these public folders?  are you connecting to a shared inbox from your profile?   Need a bit more info

Comment: Yes, these are shared folders. Each agent has a shared folder with Onshore - "their name" and then within each of those is a completed folder.

Comment: you are looking in your inbox for these shared folders, look up a couple of levels.  objnSpace.Folders - should give you a list of all the folders in profile.

Comment: I am able to get to the folders accurately, it is the loop thats the problem. When I hover over foldername(i), it does show the next folder (Ashton) but then goes through the same 10 emails from the first agent (Josh) when hovering on For Each MailItem in objFolder.Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this out through trial and error, but returns what I need.

Sub Tester()

```
'Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim MailItem
Dim EmailCount() As Integer, arrNames
Dim completed, x As Long, num As Long
Dim DayTotal


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

arrNames = Array("Ashton", "Beth", "Bree", "Brittany", "Cecilia", "Chance", "Christina", "Christine", "Dustin", "James", "Jeff", "Jenni", "Jennifer", "Jeromy", "Josh", "Josie", "Lisa", "Misti", "Nathan", "Paul", "Robert", "Sam", "Shane", "Shawna") 'add other names here...
ReDim EmailCount(LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames))

For x = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center"). _
            Folders("Onshore - " & arrNames(x)).Folders("completed")
    On Error GoTo 0

    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    num3 = 0
    num4 = 0
    num5 = 0
    num6 = 0
    num7 = 0

    Dim Totalmsg


    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
           If DateValue(Date - 1) = _
                   DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num1 = num1 + 1
           If DateValue(Date - 2) = _
                   DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num2 = num2 + 1
           If DateValue(Date - 3) = _
                   DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num3 = num3 + 1
           If DateValue(Date - 4) = _
                   DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num4 = num4 + 1
           If DateValue(Date - 5) = _
                   DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num5 = num5 + 1
           If DateValue(Date - 6) = _
                   DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num6 = num6 + 1
           If DateValue(Date - 7) = _
                   DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num7 = num7 + 1
        Next

       Dim DayTotal1 As String
       Dim DayTotal2 As String
       Dim DayTotal3 As String
       Dim DayTotal4 As String
       Dim DayTotal5 As String
       Dim DayTotal6 As String
       Dim DayTotal7 As String

        DayTotal1 = arrNames(x) & " " & (Date - 1) & " " & num1
        DayTotal2 = arrNames(x) & " " & (Date - 2) & " " & num2
        DayTotal3 = arrNames(x) & " " & (Date - 3) & " " & num3
        DayTotal4 = arrNames(x) & " " & (Date - 4) & " " & num4
        DayTotal5 = arrNames(x) & " " & (Date - 5) & " " & num5
        DayTotal6 = arrNames(x) & " " & (Date - 6) & " " & num6
        DayTotal7 = arrNames(x) & " " & (Date - 7) & " " & num7

       DayTotal = DayTotal1 & vbNewLine _
       & DayTotal2 & vbNewLine _
       & DayTotal3 & vbNewLine _
       & DayTotal4 & vbNewLine _
       & DayTotal5 & vbNewLine _
       & DayTotal6 & vbNewLine _
       & DayTotal7 & vbNewLine _

       DayTotals = DayTotals & DayTotal

         msg = arrNames(x) & "   " & (Date - 1) & "   " & num1 & vbNewLine _
         & arrNames(x) & "   " & (Date - 2) & "   " & num2 & vbNewLine _
         & arrNames(x) & "   " & (Date - 3) & "   " & num3 & vbNewLine _
         & arrNames(x) & "   " & (Date - 4) & "   " & num4 & vbNewLine _
         & arrNames(x) & "   " & (Date - 5) & "   " & num5 & vbNewLine _
         & arrNames(x) & "   " & (Date - 6) & "   " & num6 & vbNewLine _
         & arrNames(x) & "   " & (Date - 7) & "   " & num7

        ' Totalmsg = msg

        End If
    Debug.Print arrNames(x), num

Next x
MsgBox DayTotals

Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
With OutMail
.Subject = "Total Completed Tickets"
.To = "plotnerj@schneider.com"
.Body = DayTotals
.Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```